# wkhtmltopdf - cannot convert local file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf, wkhtmltopdf

I just downloaded version 10.0 for opensuse v. 11.3. I can convert a webpage (ie www.google.com) using it but cannot convert a local file. I grant all permissions on the file (& i've even tried running under sudo to no avail). This is the error:

"Loading pages (1/6) Error: Failed loading page file:///file.html".

The file exists but wkhtmltopdf refuses to load it. I even tried version 9.9 w/ the same result

What am I missing?

Comment: did you omit the full path on purpose? currently it looks like your file is placed in the root of the file system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide the full path.  Using `file:///` does not make use of the current working directory.  Rather, it specifies the path to the file from the root of the file system.

Comment: Relative path works for me. footerSettings.HtmUrl = "wwwroot/footer.html"

Answer (score 35):

Just as a notice to any future people. I couldn't get the accepted answer working on Ubuntu 14.04, so I resorted to piping my HTML to the `wkhtmltopdf` command like so:

`cat test.html | wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf`

This is from the `wkhtmltopdf` command-line help:

> Use - for stdin or stdout

Answer (score 5):

Try with this option :

```
wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access
```

It works for me.